# Azure DevOps integration with Private Channels of Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I have connected Microsoft Teams with my Azure DevOps organisation. Azure DevOps option appears under the conversation textbox in public channels, but it does not appear under the private channels. Is Azure DevOps integration not available for private channels or are there any additional actions required to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a channel under teams conversation as private and you need to uncheck the tab to show channel in everyone's list.
[image]

Comment: I have couple of existing private channels. I cannot find any option to show Private Channel in everyone's list.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your description we have found article for Create a service hook for Azure DevOps Services with Microsoft Teams :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=azure-devops, kindly check if its helps to target your concern.

Since Azure DevOps with Microsoft Teams is related with Azure DevOps Services and for that we have dedicate support team.
So, for achieving this such kind of requirement we recommend you to kindly post your query to Azure DevOps Services support via
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/. That team
will better assist you for such kind of requirement.

Answer (score -2):

> Is Azure DevOps integration not available for private channels or are there any additional actions required to enable this?

To create private channels in Microsoft Teams, you could following below steps:

1. Go to the team you want to create the private channel for and choose
   More options  **More options button > Add channel**.
2. Enter a name and description for your channel.
3. Under **Privacy**, select the down arrow on the right, and then select
   **Private – Accessible only to a specific group of people within the
   team**.
4. Select **Add**. This adds a private channel to the team.

You could check this thread [Create a channel in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-channel-in-teams-fda0b75e-5b90-4fb8-8857-7e102b014525) for some more details.

**Important**, as the document [Private channels in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels#private-channel-creation) stated:

> By default, any team owner or team member can create a private
> channel. **Guests can't create them**. The ability to create private
> channels can be managed at the team level and at the organization
> level. Use policies to control which users in your organization are
> allowed to create private channels. Once you've set the policies, team
> owners can turn off or turn on the ability for members to create
> private channels in the Settings tab for a team.

So, if you could not create or update the  private channels, you need make sure you are the **team owner or team member** of the team instead of **Guests**.

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for responding. However, my question is about Azure DevOps integration with Microsoft Teams Private Channel.